# If I have two Spherical harmonic series equal to one another, are the coefficients the same?

Tags: spherical-harmonics

Let's say I have the Spherical harmonic series decomposition of a tensor with given series coefficients, and it is equal to another spherical harmonic series decomposition with unknown coefficients.  Are the series coefficients necessarily equal?   What is their relation if not?

Comment: I feel like it could only vary up to a phase factor in the harmonics pulled into the coefficient?

Comment: Orthogonality relations should reveal the relation?

Comment: What is the difference of the tensors? What are its coefficients?